# permanent fix for export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: ubuntu, arm64

I am a newbie in Linux and just set up a VM in Oracle cloud using Ubuntu 20.04 with ARM64(Aarch64).
A python module I installed only works if I have used the below command every time I open the terminal.

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

**I want it to load every time I open the terminal or run in VS code.**
i try

```
sudo vi ~/.bashrc
```

Then add `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` at the last line.

However, it shows

```
bash: /home/ubuntu/.bashrc: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: /home/ubuntu/.bashrc: line 1: `# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.'
```

Screenshot of bashrc
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfCeS.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/83rZ1.png

Comment: You tell us what you add in `.bashrc`'s _last_ line, and also mention an error message that applies to its _first_ line. Guess what file's content would be good to post here. ;)

Comment: Looks like you introduced a syntax error into the file. You can try posting the file content - lines you changed in the file, from the error message and your description - first and last lines.

Comment: @OlafKock I added `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` at the last line

Comment: You already said so, but the error message does not apply to the last line...

Comment: @YuriFeldman I added the screenshot of the bashrc as above

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information. Also see [ask].

Comment: Do not use writer (or microsoft word for that matter) to edit or view code - it may modify the file in surprising ways. Use a text editor - gedit or vscode. You probably have a syntax error in the file. Also, you probably need the "export" in the line if you use .bashrc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better way to fix this is to add /usr/local/lib to your default ld.so.conf.  Add a file /etc/ld.so.conf.d/local.conf that contains one line:

```
/usr/local/lib
```

and then run `sudo ldconfig` and you should no longer need that (or any) LD_LIBRARY_PATH setting

Comment: newbie here. Could you elaborate clearer of the steps? Your steps do not require `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Comment: Thanks `sudo ldconfig` will do the job